# EmberJS 2.3.0 reusable functions

Tags: ember.js

I defined a component that will be the sidebar on all my web pages. Inside this component there is a section that I want to write that shows the next three meeting dates. To generate these dates, I wrote some custom javascript functions, created the array of dates and then attached it to the model. This was done in the index routes file. From there I can pass that array into the component

```
{{main-sidebar model=model.meetingDates}}
```

So in my index route, this is how I built it, which works fine.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    var getThirdWed = function(customDate, currentDate, wedCount) {
      // Keep uping the date of the month till we hit a wed
      while (customDate.getDay() !== 3) {
        customDate.setDate(customDate.getDate() + 1);
      }

      // Set date based of wedCount
      customDate.setDate(customDate.getDate() + (7 * (wedCount - 1)));

      if (customDate.getTime() > currentDate) {
        var month = customDate.toLocaleString("en-us", {
          month: "long"
        });
        var ordinal = "th";

        if (customDate.getDate() < 3) {
          ordinal = "st";
        }

        if (customDate.getDate() > 20) {
          ordinal = "st";
        }

        return month + " " + customDate.getDate() + "" + ordinal + " at 7:15pm";
      }

      return "";
    };

    var getNextMeeting = function(meetingCount, wedCount) {
      var now = new Date();
      var currentDate = now.getTime();
      var customDate = now;

      // Set the date to the first of the month
      customDate.setDate(1);

      // If meetingCount is 0 that means we want the current month
      if (meetingCount === 0) {
        return getThirdWed(customDate, currentDate, wedCount);
      } else {
        // Set to a future month
        customDate.setMonth(customDate.getMonth() + meetingCount);

        return getThirdWed(customDate, currentDate, wedCount);
      }

      return "";
    };

    var meetingDates = [];
    var count = 0;

    while (count < 3) {
      var date = getNextMeeting(count, 3);

      if(date !== '') {
        meetingDates.push(date);
        count++;
      }
    }

    model.meetingDates = meetingDates;

    return model;
  },
});
```

So next I generate a new route called cost. So do I have to duplicate all the code to generate the date array again or is there a better place to put those JS function so I can reuse them on all pages?

Comment: If you are looking for a code review you should try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, if there's a question here it is could you please formulate it better as it is hard to understand.

Comment: @Kitler "Is there a way to make component specific models?" this seems to be the relevant question. I'm not a subject expert, but that seems sufficiently understandable for me. On a related note this question is probably off-topic for Code Review (or at least a bad fit) since it asks for a rather specific change in what the code does

Comment: You have a sidebar component, but you don't want it to display on every page? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: I want the component on every page, but I do not want to rewrite my js for getting the date array in every route I create

Comment: Can you put the logic for it in the larger application scope, as in app/routes/application?